# Type of Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, types, rxjs, frontend

How to write the correct type instead of any in finction getAll()

```
getAll(): Observable<any> {
return this.http
  .get<{
    results: CharacterData[];
    info: CharacterInfo;
  }>(characterUrl)
  .pipe(map((el) => el));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an interface of the correct type, then use that instead of `any`. Same with your `.get<...>` or stick with the method you're currently doing.

*Interface:*

```
interface CorrectType {
    results: CharacterData[];
    info: CharacterInfo;
}
```

---

*Using Interface:*

```
getAll(): Observable<CorrectType> {
    return this.http.get<CorrectType>(characterUrl).pipe(map((el) => el));
}
```

*Using original method:*

```
getAll(): Observable<{
        results: CharacterData[];
        info: CharacterInfo;
    }> {
    return this.http
        .get<{
            results: CharacterData[];
            info: CharacterInfo;
        }>(characterUrl)
        .pipe(map((el) => el));
}
```